# A Java profiler that shows methods being run in a timeline?

Tags: java, profiling, desktop

I am looking for a java (desktop) profiler that shows thread timeline with details on what methods are being executed by each thread at each time point. A desktop java analogue for Android's `traceview` would be excellent.

The problem I want to solve is to find out what my threads are wainting for. I see that 3 worker threads are waiting for `main` thread to complete something (there are several lenghy tasks in there) and I need to determine what task is the longest in `main` to optimise (or parallel) it.

This Netbeans profiler screenshot probably explains the question that I need answered:

[image: Netbeans profiler]

This is what I'd like to see. The problem is, it's a tool for android

[image: Android traceview]

Comment: Maybe not really an answer, but have you tried jstack? It's an executable that should have shipped with your JDK that gives you a stack trace over every thread in a particular JVM. Might give you the info you're looking for.

Comment: This way finding a right time to collect stack trace is the tricky part. I might see the right method, and I might not, and no way to tell apart.

Comment: @akaIDIOT is right. Suppose that `wait`, if removed, would save 50% of the time. Then if you run `jstack` 10 times, the chance is more than 50% on each occasion that it will show you who is doing the waiting and why. So the bigger the problem is, the easier it is to see. The smaller it is, the less you need to be concerned.